# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver не находится при установки JDBC Realm

Tags: java, tomcat

```
   <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
      driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3030/coupon_system?user=somename;password=somepassword"
      userTable="user" userNameCol="nickname" userCredCol="password"
      userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role"/>
```

> > java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
> >         at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:651)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.startInternal(JDBCRealm.java:724)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
> >     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
> >         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
> >         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> >         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> >         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> >         at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:647)
> >         ... 16 more

- Catalina_Home и Catalina_Base установленны в Environment Variables..
- **Если кто сможет помочь буду рад!**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коннектор должен быть в папке lib

Answer (score 0):

1. Чтобы решить данную проблему вам нужно подключить драйвер в "ваш проект" а именно ODBC коннектор. Если вы скачиваете коннектор на сайте MYSQL смотрите примеры тут https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager
2. Чтобы подключить JDBC драйвер к проекту смотрите видео тут  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwYtFvGzB-U
   всё аналогично в любом редакторе.
3. Смотрите название драйвера так как он различны в разных версиях
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jc.jdbc.Driver"); - новая версия драйвера!
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); - старая версия драйвера :(